# Creating a grid in pygame using for loops

Tags: python, grid, pygame

This is different to the other questions as it uses another method. I have the following code and need to change it so that it produces a grid (all rows and columns filled in) as per Figure 16.7 on this link: http://programarcadegames.com/index.php?chapter=array_backed_grids

The following code produces a full row and a full column, but I can't quite work out how to extend it to fill the whole screen with rectangles with the appropriate margin built in.

Code:

```
    """
 Create a grid with rows and colums
"""

import pygame

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

# Set the width and height of the screen [width, height]
size = (255, 255)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

width=20
height=20
margin=5
# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Main event loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             done = True

    # --- Game logic should go here

    # --- Screen-clearing code goes here

     # Here, we clear the screen to white. Don't put other drawing commands
    # above this, or they will be erased with this command.

    # If you want a background image, replace this clear with blit'ing the
    # background image.
    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # --- Drawing code should go here
    #for column (that is along the x axis) in range (0 = starting position,     100=number to go up to, width+margin =step by (increment by this number)
    #adding the 255 makes it fill the entire row, as 255 is the size of the screen (both ways)
    for column in range(0+margin,255,width+margin):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE, [column,0+margin,width,height])
        for row in range(0+margin,255,width+margin):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[0+margin,row,width,height])
        #This simply draws a white rectangle to position (column)0,(row)0 and of size width(20), height(20) to the screen



    # --- Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 60 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

# Close the window and quit.
pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in the inner loop (`for row in`...),
where the rect is drawn with:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[0+margin,row,width,height])
```

Note that the x coordinate always is `0+margin`,
no matter which column is currently drawn. So
the code draws 10 columns on top of each other.
As a simple fix, change the line to:

```
pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,[column,row,width,height])
```

You might then notice that the other call of the draw method in the outer loop is completely unnecessary. After all, the inner call now draws a rectangle for each row in each column. So you can reduce the loop code to:

```
for column in range(0+margin, 255, width+margin):
    for row in range(0+margin, 255, height+margin):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, [column,row,width,height])
```